# How to word wrap text in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a UITextView contained within a UIScrollView. The UITextView is loaded dynamically depending on the UISegmentedControl, but I don't know how to word wrap it so the word moves to the next line.

[image]

.m:

```
@interface Tester ()
{
    UITextView *sponsor;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    sponsorInfo = [ [UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.sponsorsScrollView.frame];

    [sponsor setEditable:NO];
}

- (IBAction)control:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    if (self.sponsorSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        [self changeGenericAbout:self.cellIndex];
    }
    else
    {
        //
    }
}

- (void)changeGenericAbout:(int)index
{
    if (index == 0)
    {
        sponsorInfo.text = @"[text in screen shot]";


        [sponsor sizeToFit];
        [self.sponsorsScrollView addSubview:sponsor];
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this word wrapping in iOS 7+?

Comment: Use attributedText to set text to UITextView.

Answer (score 5):

First off I think your textview looks a bit strange. Shouldn't there be a margin on the right side as well? Now it sort of looks like the textview continues to the right. Are the frames correct or have you done something to the textContainerInset?

Anyway to answer your question regarding changing linebreaks: a textview's textContainer property has a lineBreakMode which could be set to NSLineBreakByWordWrapping. I think that should solve it

Comment: UITextView does not contain a lineBreakMode attribute. You're thinking of a UILabel, which I'm not using.

Comment: No, the UITextView doesn't, but the [NSTextContainer](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/textContainer) of the UITextView does.

Comment: I did some tests and it seems as if the textview always tries to wordwrap though, regardless of that setting. I would consider looking at the different frames in your case. I think you will find the problem there.

Comment: in viewDidLoad, I added "textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:self.sponsorsScrollView.bounds.size]; textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping; sponsorInfo = [ [UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.sponsorsScrollView.frame textContainer:textContainer];" but now there is no text

Comment: Ah you shouln't have to create a textcontainer, it comes with the textview. Is the textview frame correct?

Comment: I do not have enough rep to start a chat, if you have - please do. The screenshot you provided makes me think that line-breaking isn't your real problem

Comment: @Pangu did this get solved? I'm having the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498316/uitextview-in-collectionview-wrapping

Comment: yourUiTextView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;